# Container cannot inject EntityManager using @PersistentContext

Tags: jpa, ejb, websphere, jpa-2.0, websphere-7

Although this question has been asked several times here I cannot find the solution of my problem.

**Here is my EJB:**

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerManagerBean implements CustomerManager,
        CustomerManagerRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "OldDataBase", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;

@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
    public Customer getCustomer(final CustomerPK customerPK) {

cust = entityManager.find(Customer.class, customerPK);
//Do some stuff
}
```

***The entityManager is null. So I am getting null pointer exception. ***

**Pesistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="OldDataBase" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/legacyDs</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.rax.pk.CustomerPK</class>
        <class>com.rax.entity.Customer</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode"
                value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="db2" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="OracleDB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>
            org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
        </provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/cssDs</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode"
                value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Error:**

```
0000002a CustAdminProf E com.staples.cacs.appsessions.CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean getCustAdminProfileStatus  Domain layer Error occured while processing  getCustAdminProfileStatus() 
                                 com.staples.cacs.domain.exception.DomainObjectsException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.staples.cacs.domain.entitymanagers.CustomerManagerBean.getCustomer(CustomerManagerBean.java:216)
    at com.staples.cacs.domain.entitymanagers.interfaces.EJSRemote0SLCustomerManagerBean_89163ebf.getCustomer(EJSRemote0SLCustomerManagerBean_89163ebf.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil$4.run(ProxyUtil.java:726)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:241)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil.invokeWithClassLoaders(ProxyUtil.java:724)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1161)
    at $Proxy24.getCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.staples.cacs.domain.entitymanagers.interfaces._CustomerManagerRemote_Stub.getCustomer(_CustomerManagerRemote_Stub.java)
    at com.staples.cacs.appsessions.CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.getMasterAccStatus(CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.java:1791)
    at com.staples.cacs.appsessions.CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.getCustAdminProfileStatus(CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.java:823)
    at com.staples.cacs.appsessions.CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.getCustAdminProfileStatus(CustAdminProfileAppSessionBean.java:760)
    at com.staples.cacs.appsessions.interfaces.EJSRemote0SLCustAdminProfileAppSessionBean_e64c4c7c.getCustAdminProfileStatus(EJSRemote0SLCustAdminProfileAppSessionBean_e64c4c7c.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil$4.run(ProxyUtil.java:726)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:241)
    at com.ibm.rmi.util.ProxyUtil.invokeWithClassLoaders(ProxyUtil.java:724)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.invoke(ClientDelegate.java:1161)
    at $Proxy20.getCustAdminProfileStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.staples.cacs.appsessions.interfaces._CustAdminProfileAppSessionRemote_Stub.getCustAdminProfileStatus(_CustAdminProfileAppSessionRemote_Stub.java)
    at com.staples.cacs.web.security.PostLoginFilter.doFilter(PostLoginFilter.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.staples.cacs.web.util.SetHttpHeadersFilter.doFilter(SetHttpHeadersFilter.java:29)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:840)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:750)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.invokeFilters(WebApp.java:3629)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.invokeFilters(WebApp.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3492)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:818)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.staples.cacs.domain.entitymanagers.CustomerManagerBean.getCustomer(CustomerManagerBean.java:167)
    ... 52 more
```

I am using RAD 7.5 & IBM WebSphere Application Server 6.1. The code seems to be ok. Because these are my client's code which I have not changed. There seems to be some issues regarding WAS configuration. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created the datasource ? Do you see any other errors in the log ? If yes, post them.

Comment: Yeah I have created the datasource. I have tested the connection & it was successful. The jndi name is also same. I will edit the question and will put the entire error. @rangalo

Comment: Are you packaging a copy of the `PersistenceContext` annotation in your application?  You might try starting the server with `-verbose:class` just to double check; the `PersistenceContext` class should only be loaded by WebSphere Application Server if you want container-managed JPA injection to work.

Comment: Thanks bkail. But can you tell me how to start the sever with `-verbose:class` ? Actually while doing the entityManager.find() it is searching a table in a db2 database that is in a AS400 system. I can test the connection successfully to that datasource. But do I need to do any message queue configuration in WAS to find any data on that AS400 Db2 database table?@bkail

Comment: @SumitPal You would add it to the generic JVM arguments on the Java Virtual Machine settings page in the admin console.  It's good that your test connection is working, but the NPE indicates an error occurred at a higher-level before any attempt is made to access the database, so those configuration details aren't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There should be other messages in the log that would indicate this is the problem, but I know that earlier versions of RAD 7.5 had an issue with multiple persistence-units defined in a single persistence.xml file.  Have you tried modifying your persistence.xml to only contain the single persistence-unit that you are trying to utilize?  If nothing else, this might help narrow down the specific issue.  Earlier versions of OpenJPA had a similar issue at runtime of detecting the proper persistence-unit.  But, in either case, I thought there were messages logged to indicate the problem.  I'd try this separation to see if you can make progress.  Good luck.

Comment: I just did what you have told. But the same error is coming. system.out log also has no extra information.  Actually while doing the entityManager.find() it is searching a table in a db2 database that is in a AS400 system. I can test the connection successfully to that datasource. But do I need to do any message queue configuration in WAS to find any data on that AS400 Db2 database table?

Comment: I'm confused, Sumit Pal.  The original error posted was for an NPE because the @PersistenceContext injection wasn't working.  So, if that is not working, then there is no way you are getting to the entityManager.find() operation since your entityManager would be null.

Re:  your question about a message queue... No.  No additional message queue configuration is required to retrieve data from an AS/400 database table.  Just the standard datasource configuration.